# How to test SAML without paying for a business account?

Tags: web-services, saml, saml-2.0

I am building a SAML Identity Provider (IdP) as a proof of concept.

I want to test if my IdP works with real-world services like Office 365, Dropbox, Salesforce, etc. However, I don't want to pay for those business accounts. I don't need to use a business account for work, but I want to test the SAML only.

Is there any way for me to test my SAML feature with those services?

If there is none, how could I prove that my IdP is integrated correctly with those services?

Answer (score 0):

There are some free SAML services for [client](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43) and [server side](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-idp-to-test-now-477761595b60).